# Normalizing (composing and decomposing) utf8 strings in Swift

Tags: swift, string, unicode, unicode-normalization

Characters with accents in Unicode strings can be represented in a "short" (composed) and "long" (decomposed) format. This means in Xcode string `a` has a length of 8 and string `b` has a length of 10 even though they appear the same:

```
let a:String = "δέκα" // 8 bytes
print(a.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!.count)

let b:String = "δέκα" // 10 bytes
print(b.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!.count)
```

[image]

I need to "shrink" strings to ensure they are always in the shorter "composed" format. How is this done in Swift?

---

**Footnote:** I know that it is  possible to completely strip accents like this (below). I don't want to do that, I just want to "compose" the characters.

```
let usPosixLocale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let out = "δέκα".folding(options: [.caseInsensitive, .diacriticInsensitive], locale: usPosixLocale)
```

I am aware of the `.widthInsensitive` option, but the documentation appears to indicate that it's only for asian characters. So specifically, this does *not* work to compose or decompose characters:

```
let out = a.folding(options: [.widthInsensitive], locale: usPosixLocale)
```

---

**UPDATE**

Here is a second longer version of the code that shows the byte difference for clarity.

```
let a:String = String(bytes:[206, 180, 206, 173, 206, 186, 206, 177], encoding:.utf8)!
print(a, a.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!.count)

let b:String = String(bytes:[206, 180, 206, 181, 204, 129, 206, 186, 206, 177], encoding:.utf8)!
print(b, b.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!.count)

let usPosixLocale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
let out = b.folding(options: [.widthInsensitive], locale: usPosixLocale)
    print(out.data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!.count)
```

[image]

Comment: I get `8` for both of these when I copy/paste from here into an iPad Playground (Swift 5.3) See https://imgur.com/VsXdFpc

Comment: Can you share the UTF8 units output for both `a` & `b` using `for unit in a.utf8 {
    print(unit)
}`

Comment: Perhaps Stackoverflow or the browser copy and paste normalized it. I'll work out how to put the bytes in.

Comment: Ok, I have added a second longer (but harder to read) copy of the same code, where the strings are represented as bytes, so that the code is definitely reproducible)

Comment: I think the word you want is "normalize".   https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542778-cfstringnormalize

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1412645-precomposedstringwithcanonicalma) does the normalization:

```
let a = "δέκα"
print(a, Data(a.utf8).count) // δέκα 8

let b = "δε\u{0301}κα"
print(b, Data(b.utf8).count) // δέκα 10

let bn = b.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping
print(bn, Data(bn.utf8).count) // δέκα 8
```

A “literal“ comparison demonstrates that `a` is identical to `bn`, but not to `b`:

```
print(b.compare(a, options: .literal) == .orderedSame)  // false
print(bn.compare(a, options: .literal) == .orderedSame) // true
```

*Remarks:* `precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping` produces the “Unicode Normalization Form C.” There is also `precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping` which produces the “Unicode Normalization Form KC.” See

- [1.2 Normalization Forms](https://unicode.org/reports/tr15/#Norm_Forms)

in the Unicode Standard for the precise differences. Roughly, the latter folds more differences which are “inappropriately distinguished in many circumstances.” Examples:

```
let c = "\u{fb01}" // LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FI
print(c, c.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping, c.precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping)
// ﬁ ﬁ fi

let d = "2\u{2075}"
print(d, d.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping, d.precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping)
// 2⁵ 2⁵ 25

let e = "\u{2165}" // ROMAN NUMERAL SIX
print(e, e.precomposedStringWithCanonicalMapping, e.precomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping)
// Ⅵ Ⅵ VI
```

Answer (score 3):

Thank you *@matt* for pointing to [`CFStringNormalize(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1542778-cfstringnormalize)

Here's how you can do this -

```
import Foundation
import CoreFoundation

extension String {
    func normalizedCanonicallyComposed() -> String {
        let mutable = NSMutableString(string: self) as CFMutableString
        CFStringNormalize(mutable, .KC) // OR .C
        return mutable as String
    }
}
```

Usage

```
let a: String = String(bytes: [206, 180, 206, 173, 206, 186, 206, 177], encoding: .utf8)!
print(a, a.data(using: .utf8)!.count)

let b: String = String(bytes: [206, 180, 206, 181, 204, 129, 206, 186, 206, 177], encoding: .utf8)!
print(b, b.data(using: .utf8)!.count)
        
print("Before - \(b), count: \(b.data(using: .utf8)!.count)")
let c = b.normalizedCanonicallyComposed()
print("After - \(c), count: \(c.data(using: .utf8)!.count)")
```

Output

```
δέκα 8
δέκα 10
Before - δέκα, count: 10
After - δέκα, count: 8
```